# PHP Mail function and foreign domains

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

PHP Mail function seems to have issues sending emails TO: @domain.edu.ag.  Does the function support foreign domains?

The domain is hosted on Google Apps so mail should be received in the same way.  No messages are in SPAM which lead me to explore further.  So I created a test script to send mail, and noticed that mail doesn't seem to be sending.

This is what I used for testing purposes:

```
<?php
    $to = "mymail@domain.edu.ag,mymail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Hi!";
    $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    } else {
    echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
    }
    ?>
```

The result was that the @gmail message was received but not the @edu.ag email address.  What's going on here?  There are not errors or anything and mail is received just fine from other senders.

Comment: No, PHP's mail() function doesn't have problems with foreign domains. Mail() just uses whatever the system is configured with (e.g. sendmail) so you'd be best to check the system logs and possible the host you're sending to who may be blocking or rejecting your tests.

Comment: What happens if you swap the email addresses around in your $to string? Does the email to gmail still get sent, and the .edu.ag one not arrive? How about if you just send to the .edu.ag address?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead:

```
$to = array("mymail@domain.edu.ag", "mymail@gmail.com");
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

foreach($to as $to_addr) {
    mail($to_addr, $subject, $body)
}
```

So you are looping through the email addresses in the array, and  sending the mail statement for each one.  I've had some trouble in the past using a regular string with commas.

Comment: Thanks but the root problem is that even if I send the message to 1 email address then replace it with the other, the gmail is received but not the foreign domain.  Isn't that strange?